# How can i accurately import "dates" from .csv files in SAS?

Tags: date, csv, import, sas

I am trying to import .csv files in SAS and they include dates and times.

In csv files, they are defined as "m-d-yyyy hh:mm:ss" (I am not allowed to change the data in excel but I have to work just on SAS).

The problem is that when SAS reads it, it thinks m is a and d is m. :(

For example, what is "9-1-2016 8:00:57" in excel is converted as 09JAN16:08:00:57 in SAS.

I want formats like 01SEP16:08:00:57.

How can i accurately import dates from .csv files in SAS?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code that you tried that did not work?

Comment: Do you actually have a CSV file or an Excel file?  If you are looking at your CSV file after it has been opened by Excel then you might not be seeing hat is really in the CSV file as Excel will transform the data after opening it.

Comment: Set the locale/date format settings in excel so it displays as M-D-YYYY

Comment: SAS has informats which should help...

Comment: I created an excel spreadsheet and noticed I needed to create a custon format to match what you have  "9-1-2016 8:00:57"  the format I used was m-d-yyyy hh:mm:ss  when I imported the file into sas 9.3 it worked fine.  What excel format are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your comments.. Actually, yesterday I realized I could use R instead of SAS. I solved the problem using as.POSIXct and strptime in R. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I see that you've solved this by using R instead. In case anyone wants an answer for this in future:

One thing you can try is to change your options so that SAS reads as MDY instead of DMY. The way to do this is to run:

```
options datestyle=mdy;
```